# Cannot display image using python in anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Despite trying multiple solution i could find on here.
It seems like the image still fail to show.
Any one could kindly shed some light on this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using anaconda Jupiter notebook
The current python version is 3.7.3

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test")
load = Image.open(r'C:\t.jpg')
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)  
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see your issue now. PhotoImage loads the image into memory, but doesn't draw it.

Try putting this before `window.mainloop()`:

```
    . . .
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
canvas = new Canvas(window, width=500, height=500) # Change the height and width to suit your image
canvas.pack() # Put the canvas on the window
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=render) # Put the image on the canvas
```

Comment: it show syntax error, please kindly advise, thanks. File "<ipython-input-21-ebbc5699306c>", line 13
    canvas = new Canvas(window, width=500, height=500) # Change the height and width to suit your image
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, remove the 'new'. Gotten used to C :~)